# ADODataSet: есть ли событие, реагирующее на изменение набора данных?

Tags: события, delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в `ADODataSet` событие, реагирующее на изменение набора данных? Пробовал `AfterRefresh`, `OnRecordsetChangeComplete`, `OnWillChangeRecordset` (ставил в них `ShowMessage('Hello!')`), но почему-то ни одно из них не отрабатывает. Может, есть какие-то тонкости, или надо использовать другое событие? (мне нужно отловить момент, когда набор данных становится пуст)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `TADODataSet` такого тоже не нашел, но есть у `TDataSource` событие `OnDataChange`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, приму к сведению!

Answer (score 1):

В конце концов остановился на AfterOpen + отдельно обрабатываю изменение фильтра.